# Watermark strategy on Flink Kinesis Consumer

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am investigating using Flink with a Kinesis stream as a source. I would like to use Event Time watermarking.
Planning on running this on AWS managed Flink (Kinesis Analytics) platform.

Looking at the AWS documentation and indeed [Flink documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/) it is recommended to use the FlinkKinesisConsumer.
To enable EventTime on this consumer I see that the recommendation is to use a custom `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks()` and set it on the `KinesisConsumer` with `setPeriodicWatermarkAssigner`.

However, I also read on the Flink documentation that this API is deprecated and it advised to use WatermarkStrategies.

My questions:

- is it possible to use the WatermarkStrategy on the kinesis consumer or must it be applied after a non-source operation on the DataStream itself (discouraged in flink docs)?
- if not possible and must be used after a non-source operation what does this mean? Why is it discouraged? how does it will performance of the workload
- Or is it recommended to continue to use a deprecated API?
- or is there another kinesis flink consumer than can be recommended

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Alexis

Comment: The `WatermarkStrategy` contains both the `TimestampAssigner` and the `WatermarkGenerator` and they are working in hand and hand. So, where did you read that the assigner API is deprecated?

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala - it's from the flink docs at the bottom of this page: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/
The Kinesis consumer takes an AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks - this is deprecated

Comment: Should also add that kinesis docs also stipulate adding the method `setStreamTimeCharacteristic()` on the StreamExecutionEnvironment - which is also deprecated.

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using in KDA? 1.11?

Comment: The latest version - 1.13
The same methods and docs show these things deprecated in flink 1.13

Comment: [Before 1.12 the default](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#introduction-to-time-attributes) TimeCharacteristic was ProcessingTime. In [1.12](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/12/10/release-1.12.0.html#important-changes) this has been changed to EventTime so that's why the `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` become deprecated.

Comment: Ah cool. So that explains that. But then the questions still remains - how to implement a Watermark strategy on a Kinesis consumer without using deprecated methods?

Comment: As far as I can see from the [github source code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connector-flink) of the connector it is compatible with 1.11. The [`FlinkKinesisConsumer`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connector-flink/blob/master/amazon-kinesis-connector-flink/src/main/java/software/amazon/kinesis/connectors/flink/FlinkKinesisConsumer.java#L259) does not expose a method which anticipates a WatermarkingStrategy  . So I think it is fine to use the `setPeriodicWatermarkAssigner` method.

Comment: Yeah. But I think it then also relies (according to docs and examples on Flink github) with a `setStreamTimeCharacteristic`. So to use a Watermark strategy with a kinesis consumer I believe the only way is to not set it on the source itself but on the stream and let Flink create a new stream from this and apply the Watermark strategy there. Thanks for all your help here @PeterCsala

Comment: Yepp, calling the `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on a `DataStream<T>` is also viable option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set it directly on `FlinkKinesisConsumer` (excepting, as you pointed out, by using the deprecated `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` interface) nor any other implementation of `SourceFunction`, but you can set the watermarks as soon as you get the datastream.

Judging from the comments I think you've already figured it out, but this is what I'm doing.

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer;

// Set up
var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
var consumerProperties = ...;
var deserializer = ...;
var kinesisConsumer = new FlinkKinesisConsumer<MyDataType>(kinesisStreamName, deserializer, consumerProperties);

// Pick a watermark strategy.
// Use some timestamp field from your event object.
var strategy = WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps<MyDataType>()
                                .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp());

// Start reading from Kinesis
var dataStream = env.addSource(kinesisConsumer)
                    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(strategy);
```

You'll have to tweak this to your use case. Obviously replace `MyDataType` with whatever is actually in your stream, but also note that `forMonotonousTimestamps` may not be suited to your use case, and `forBoundedOutOfOrderness` may work better.